# Debug Acumatica Process Failure

Tags: acumatica

I have a client that is trying to run the Validate Customer Balances process in accounts receivable and the process does not finish. What tools are available to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to determine whether the process finishes with an error or is simply taking a long time.

This process has a specific warning stating that balance validation takes a long time:
[image]

If you see the process progress indicator spinning, it's most likely just taking a long time. In that case you should either wait until the process finishes or follow the warning to select fewer customer.
[image]

If the processes finishes with an error indicator:
[image]

Open the trace window and run the process again, error details are usually visible in traces. For example, if you see financial period is inactive in traces then you can resolve it by going to the financial period screen and activating it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica's **T190 Quick Start In Customization** and **T270 Workflow API** documentations describe the Debugging Process while working with Acumatica.

When you install a new Acumatica version, You must put the *Install Debugger Tool* checkbox.

[image: Acumatica Installer]

You must open Visual Studio project as Admin.

To be able to debug the site's original source code, find *web.config* file of the Acumatica instance. Setting of Vistal Studio also must be changed as described in documentation.

[image: XML code of instance]

Change the "False" value to "True".

Go to *Debug->Attach to Process...* or press *Ctrl+Alt+P*. Search for w3wp.exe, select the instance you needed and Press Attach.

[image: Attach to Process]

Then put breakpoints and do debugging as you would do in any other project not related to Acumatica.